# Publishing in .NET produces "Application Files\MyApp_SomeVersionNumber" How to get this number?

Tags: c#, .net, publish

When I publish my app it gives me a name like

Application Files\WPFMapLauncher_1_0_0_43

I can get the 1.0.0.0 with this :

```
String version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
```

But how can I get the 43?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update **both** manually/OR in any other way:

`Assembly Version` ***AND*** `File version` in Project Properties.

Comment: updated :p, I felt that there was something wrong! Thanks for letting me know.